# Settings for com ports to speed device I/O data transfers

Tags: windows, io, com

I used to be able to go to com port settings for device I/O on windows and change settings such as baud rate for computer between internal PC hardware. I'm looking for instructions to do the same thing on a windows 10 PC.

Comment: The setting for baud rate is in Control Panel, Phone and Modem. You need a Modem installed or you will not see the settings. Since modems are not used much any more, the settings do not appear in the main Phone/Modem settings.

Comment: You can also find Device Settings in Device Manager, Com Port. There is information there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still do that in Windows 10:

- Run *Start > Device Manager*
- Double-click the type of device  to configure, for example
  "Ports (COM & LPT)"
- Right-click the device to configure and select Properties
- Select the Resources tab
- Click to clear "Use automatic settings"
  (it's unavailable and appears dimmed for devices for which there are
  no settings to configure or are controlled by Plug and Play)
- In "Settings based on" select the hardware configuration to modify,
  for example "Basic configuration 0000"
- In "Resource settings", select the resource to modify,
  for example "IRQ"
- Click "Change Setting"
- In "Edit Resource" type the new value and then OK
- Repeat the above for all the resource settings that you want to modify
- Quit Device Manager and reboot.

Comment: Thank you, harrymc https://superuser.com/users/8672/harrymc. This answer is just what I need. Before I clear settings such as for hard drives and CPUs, do you happen to know or have a resource for what explicit settings to type in to optimize and accelerate I/O communications on and off these devices?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have such data.

Comment: Thank you. I don't find a Resources tab under any of the device properties. However, you were very helpful in confirming how to do it, and I see I have some more research ahead of me. I use Prio, which enables me to set higher priorities for processes in Task Manager permanently, and I'll have to see whether this works for I/O priorities.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 has the **Device Manager** interface that was in previous Windows versions. There are many ways to get to the device manager page:

1. You can go directly to the **Device Manager** page by typing `devmgmt.msc` in the **Run** interface opened using the `Windows + R` shortcut.
2. Copy `Control Panel\Hardware and Sound` to **File Explorer** and go to **Devices and Printers > Device Manager** page.
3. You can access the **Hardware and Sound > Devices and Printers > Device Manager** page by entering the `control` command in the **Run** interface opened by using the `Windows + R` shortcut.